# Why functions.php file automatically empty?

Tags: hacked

In many WordPress websites functions.php file is automatically erased. I checked every file. I scanned files on server but no file is infected. After an interval of time website response white page, when I checked functions.php it empty. Why this is happening. Is it a server problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can think of this is a server issue. This has happened to me once due to server crash.

I hope you have a backup of your files.